# setCategoryIds() changes product visibility to "Catalog,Search"

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

Can somebody explain why `setCategoryIds($ids)` changes the product's visibility to `Catalog,Search` from whatever else it was (in my encounter, I was working with `Search`-view products)?

Here's the code that makes all of the products in `$categoryId` to have visibility `Catalog,Search` after the `save()` when they originally had `Search`. I restored all of my products and tested it to verify as well.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection() 
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','special_price','sku','small_image'));

foreach($productCollection as $product) {
    $catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $product->setCategoryIds($catIds);
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that you're saving the product but you've not loaded the visibility as part of the product collection. `Catalog, Search` is the default visibility.

Try this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection() 
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','special_price','sku','small_image'))
    ->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
```

Now when you save the product it should retain its original visibility setting.

Comment: Ah.. Is there anything else that is "required" I need to set before the save? So that I don't unintentionally override current values with default values.

Comment: Visibility is the main culprit - however if you're trying to do things in the future like saving URL keys you need to join the attribute to the collection to be able to explicitly create rewrites, etc.

Comment: So, the `joinAttribute` is bringing the data that the given product already has when you do the inner join, right? Could you do `setVisibility(...)` instead?

Comment: Also, I implemented `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct(..)/assignProduct(..)` meanwhile, and this seems to work just in the category scope. Is this method safe with other data?

Comment: To my knowledge setVisibility would work but you really shouldn't have to re-set the visibility if it's joined already as part of the collection. The category API question is probably beyond the scope of the comments section but that sounds feasible.

Comment: I would also like to point out that `Display Product Options In` under the Product Information->Design tab gets set to the default option "Black after info column". This will need to be joined as well.